# Avoid the prompt for - the data you are pasting is not the same size- using PowerShell

Tags: excel, api, powershell

How to use powershell to avoid the prompt for "the data you are pasting isnot the same size as your selection ...." Can I avoid this using PowerShell API? I want to say "Yes" for this prompt through powershell.
I am using $myworksheet.Paste($range) but the prompt for paste and save needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress prompts and alerts like the "Paste" warning you describe by setting the [`DisplayAlerts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx) property, like so:

```
$ExcelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = $False
# Do your pasting here
```